# Place icon at right of title in a AlertDialog builder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

All the answers and info that i find at internet seems old and deprecated, i could add a simple icon at my title bar at left (user image), but i need to have 2 more images, a message and a phone at the right, like a simple user details view, the problem is that i don't know how to set the position of those images, the only thing i could do was this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Friends.this);
                final User user = usersList.get(position);
                builder.setTitle(user.getUsername());
                builder.setMessage("You wanna delete friendgroup: " + user.getUsername());
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_user);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //myRef.child("Users").child(userId).child("FriendLists").child(friend.getName()).removeValue();
                        //friendList.remove(friend);
                        //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
```

with the builder.setIcon i could add a image at the left, but how can i add more icons and at the right of my title ? do i really need a custom builder to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you need to use a custom dialog with your desired layout ...here  is an example https://inducesmile.com/android-game-development/custom-dialog-and-custom-alertdialog-box-in-android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a custom `AlertDialog`.

**Try this:**

1. Design a `RelativeLayout` that contains your icon, title and right message and phone icon and other things.
2. Set this layout to your `AlertDialog` using `setView()` method.

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Friends.this);
           final User user = usersList.get(position);

           LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
           View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null);
           builder.setView(dialogView);

           builder.setCancelable(false);
           builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   //myRef.child("Users").child(userId).child("FriendLists").child(friend.getName()).removeValue();
                   //friendList.remove(friend);
                   //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           });
           builder.show();
   ```

Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Hope this will help~

Comment: awesome you are my hero, thank you very much, just a last question, the content inside the custom how can i align it? i don't understand very well if the whole xml is the whole container of the builder

Comment: Yes, you can design any thing with xml. Can you please give me the design of your dialog... then i will try to make it for you

Comment: i am doing it i already got it, just a little thing, how can i put 2 diferent sections? i mean my upper with title with 1 color and the other white?

Comment: Create a RootRelativeLayout > Add another 2 RelativeLayout inside it > One for Title and two right icons > another for description > Give 2 relativelayout 2 different colors

Comment: @AndreSilva If my answer seems useful please give an upvote

Comment: you are awesome friend, best regards for you :)